# How to copy string between 2D character Arrays?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

not able to copy the string from 2D array cGroceName to cGroceNameBill_1.

```
void main() {

    char cGroceName[100][100];
    char cGroceNameBill_1[100][100];
    printf("\nEnter Number of Groceries:");
    scanf_s("%d", &iGrocNum);

    for (int i = 0; i < iGrocNum; i++) {
        printf ("\nEnter GroceryName:");
        scanf_s("\n%99s", cGroceName[i], sizeof cGroceName[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<iGrocNum;i++) {
        cGroceNameBill_1[i] = cGroceName[i] //--This is not working
    }

}
```

Comment: `void main()` is not a standard signature of `main`. Better use the standard `int main(void)`

Comment: What about the good old `strcpy()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you did was effectively assign one "pointer" to another.  You need to copy the string somehow, i.e. `strcpy`, `snprintf`

Change the last loop to:

```
for(int i=0;i<iGrocNum;i++) {
    snprintf(cGroceNameBill_1[i], strlen(cGroceName[i]), "%s", cGroceName[i]);
}
```

Use `snprintf` for safety.

OR use

`sprintf(cGroceNameBill_1[i], "%s", cGroceName[i]);`

I'm not sure when/where you want to print them but when you do, it's just a call to `printf`.  Really, you need to pick up a C programming book, Chapter 1-2.

```
for(int i=0;i<iGrocNum;i++) {
    printf("%s", cGroceNameBill_1[i]);
}
```

Comment: @sasha looking back at all your previous posts it's usually good form to accept an answer or 1UP an answer.

Comment: Would you also please explain, how to print the strings from the array where i copied to ?

Comment: Sure, go back and accept some the answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Would you also please explain, how to print the strings from the array where i copied to ?

Comment: I already did, what you mentioned above however its only printing 1 character with first iteration and 2 characters in 2nd iterations. :)

Comment: I'm not 100% but in `scanf_s("\n%99s", cGroceName[i], sizeof cGroceName[i]);` I believe you need to remove `\n`

Comment: Alright, sorry for previous comment actually from every string, while printing using above loop  its churning out last character.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<iGrocNum;i++) {
    snprintf(cGroceNameBill_1[i], strlen(cGroceName[i])+1, "%s", cGroceName[i]);
}   

strlen(cGroceName[i])+1 , this workrd